# Como fazer requisicão via post para a action pelo AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Não consigo acessar minha action através da requisição ajax:

```
        <legend>Procedimento:</legend>
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.CodigoProcedimento, new { id = "codProcedimento", name = "codProcedimento" })

@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.CodigoPessoa, new { id="codigoPessoa",name="codigoPessoa"}) 

@Html.Label("Descrição: ")
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Descricao, new { maxlength = "30", id = "descricao", name = "descricao" })
@Html.Label("Palavra chave: ")
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.PalavraChave, new { maxlength = "50", id = "palavraChave", name = "palavraChave" })
@Html.Label("Pergunta Panico: ")
@Html.TextAreaFor(p => p.PerguntaPanico, new { maxlength = "50", id = "perguntaPanico", name = "perguntaPanico" })
@Html.Label("Resposta Panico: ")
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.RespostaPanico, new { maxlength = "50", id = "respostaPanico", name = "respostaPanico" })
<br /><br />
@Html.Label("Procedimento Panico: ")
@Html.TextAreaFor(p => p.ProcedimentoPanico, new { maxlength = "80", id = "procedimentoPanico", name = "procedimentoPanico" })
@Html.Label("Adicionar Contactado: ")
@Html.DropDownListFor(s => s.CodContactadoPessoa, Model.ContactadoPessoa, new { id = "CodContactadoPessoa", name = "CodContactadoPessoa" })
<img src="~/Content/images/plus-18.png" onclick="atualizarCampos()"/>


         function atualizarCampos(){
    var codigoPessoa = $("#codigoPessoa").val();
    var descricao = $("#descricao").val();
    var palavraChave = $("#palavraChave").val();
    var perguntaPanico = $("#perguntaPanico").val();
    var respostaPanico = $("#respostaPanico").val();
    var procedimentoPanico = $("#procedimentoPanico").val();
    var temp = $("#CodContactadoPessoa").val();
    var codigoContactado = temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value;
    var codigoProcedimento = $("#codProcedimento").val();


    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Master/EditarProcedimentoAContacto',
            data:
                {
                    CodigoPessoa: codigoPessoa,
                    Descricao: descricao,
                    PalavraChave: palavraChave,
                    PerguntaPanico: perguntaPanico,
                    RespostaPanico: respostaPanico,
                    ProcedimentoPanico: procedimentoPanico,
                    CodPessoaProcedimento: codigoContactado,                       
                    CodigoProcedimento: codigoProcedimento,
                },
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("oi");
                $('#procedimentoresult').html(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso você tenha as versões mais recentes do jQuery tente utilizar a versão mais recente para declaração de AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'SuaURL',
    data: {
        valor1: valor1,
        valor2: valor2
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data); 
}).error(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Como outros usuários disseram verifique:

- Se sua URL é valida;
- Se você está mandando um retorno; ou seja -> `(echo json_encode($retorno))` na página onde você recebe o post;

**Exemplo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rafaelwithoeft/dr1mdynL/5/

Answer (score 0):

A URL é válida?

Está ocorrendo algum erro de JavaScript antes de completar a requisição?

Na chave `data` encontrei um erro, no ultimo valor você adicionou uma virgula no final da linha (`CodigoProcedimento: codigoProcedimento,`), remova-a.

Para ver o retorno da reposta você pode usar `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var dados = { codigoPessoa: codigoPessoa, descricao: descricao};    
$.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: JSON.stringify(dados),
                        datatype: "html",
                        success: function (data) {})
    });
```